# Как отформатировать раздел под NTFS

Tags: windows, ntfs, ubuntu

Купил новый ноут, а на нем стоит ubuntu, обычную семерку не могу поставить, пишет что надо отформатировать раздел под NTFS, как это сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Снесите линуксовый раздел (буковка "D" - Delete), а потом устанавливайте на освободившееся место! Заранее предупреждаю - возможен гемор с драйверами!

Comment: Блин, это для XP, в семёрке - чуть посложнее, там при установке надо войти в "Редактирование разделов", ну или что-то типа того, точно не помню, а потом - как написал выше!

Answer (score 0):

Установленная Вами 7-ка не будет обновляться в автоматическом режиме. А возможно, и в ручном тоже. Т.к. в BIOS данного ноута отсутствует идентификатор предустановленной Win, который запрашивают серверы обновлений (wsus).

Некоторые производители выпустили прошивки BIOS с этими идентификаторами - посмотрите на сайте, вдруг Вам повезет.